# How to get individual elements in xml tag in python from <reg regname="uid_v2" type="block_uid_v2_t" num="1" addr="0x4" incr="0x4">

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

1. List item

[enter image description here][1].

How to get the values seperately regname,type... in python. I need to get the type value and addr seperately.

```
    for regfile in root.findall('regfile'):
        reg_value = regfile.find('reg').text
        print(reg_value)
        for reg in regfile.findall('reg'):
            name = reg.find('name').text
            type = reg.find('text').text
```

I tried but it's throwing error like "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

```
    <regfile regfilename="blkreq" type="blk_required_v2_rdl_rf_t" num="1" addr="0x0" incr="0x8">
        <name><![CDATA[blk_required_v2_rdl_rf_t]]></name>
        <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
        <property name="num" value="1"/>
        <reg regname="uid_v2" type="block_uid_v2_t" num="1" addr="0x4" incr="0x4">
            <name><![CDATA[Block Unique ID Type]]></name>
            <description><![CDATA[The IPID and the Platform Type together provides Unique ID of an IP]]></description>
            <property name="msbhigh" value="1"/>
            <property name="num" value="1"/>
            <property name="retention" value=""/>
            <property name="width" value="32"/>
            <property name="shared" value="0"/>
            <property name="accesswidth" value="8"/>
            <field fieldname="ipid">
                <name><![CDATA[Design IP Identification]]></name>
                <description><![CDATA[This is reserved for future use.]]></description>
                <msb>31</msb>
                <lsb>8</lsb>
                <property name="hw_r" value="1"/>
                <property name="reset" value="0h"/>
                <property name="retention" value=""/>
                <property name="sw_r" value="1"/>
                <property name="width" value="0"/>
            </field>
            <field fieldname="platform">
                <name><![CDATA[Platform]]></name>
                <description><![CDATA[Implementation for the specific platform class (asic, fpga, vp, etc) - supplied 
           a global parameter, PLATFORM_TYPE, by the RTL and defined in the platform package in DVI_LIB. 
           The reset value shall reflect the configuration.]]></description>
                <msb>3</msb>
                <lsb>0</lsb>
                <property name="hw_w" value="1"/>
                <property name="reset" value=""/>
                <property name="retention" value=""/>
                <property name="sw_r" value="1"/>
                <property name="width" value="0"/>
            </field>
        </reg>
```

Comment: share the xml please (as part of the question)

Comment: <reg regname="uid_v2" type="block_uid_v2_t" num="1" addr="0x4" incr="0x4">
                <name><![CDATA[Block Unique ID Type]]></name>
                <description><![CDATA[The IPID and the Platform Type together provides Unique ID of an IP]]></description>
                <property name="msbhigh" value="1"/>
                <property name="num" value="1"/>
                <property name="retention" value=""/>
                <property name="width" value="32"/>
                <property name="shared" value="0"/>
                <property name="accesswidth" value="8"/>

Comment: Edit the question and add the xml please. Make sure you post a valid xml.

Comment: Added. Please Check

Comment: NOT as image - as valid xml text.

Comment: Don't have option to add file

Comment: Copy paste into the question body (or upload to pastebin if it is too big)

Comment: The XML you have posted is not a valid one. Please post a valid one.

Comment: What do you expect to get from the line ` reg_value = regfile.find('reg').text` ? What is the 'reg_value' value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for regfile in root.findall('regfile'):
        for reg in regfile.findall('reg'):
            reg_name = reg.find('name').text
            reg_name_quotes = '"'+reg_name+'"'
            reg_type = reg.get('type')
            reg_addr = reg.get('addr')
            reg_description = reg.find('description').text
```

By using get method we can get the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `xml.etree.ElementTree` package to parse your xml code into a tree, and iterate over it this way:

```
# Official DOC: 
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

x = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<regs>
    <reg regname="uid_v2" type="block_uid_v2_t" num="1" addr="0x4" incr="0x4"> </reg>
    <reg regname="uid_v3" type="block_uid_v3_t" num="3" addr="0x4" incr="0x4"> </reg>
</regs>'''

# tree = ET.parse("some_file.xml")
tree = ET.fromstring(x) # I use a string here in this example

for child in tree:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

The `child.attrib` is a dictionary: you can obtain the specific attribute **type** simply by `child.attrib["type"]`. Check out this repl.it for a [live example](https://repl.it/@dahle/xml).

**EDIT** - as requested in the comments below:

```
# Get only the relevant nodes from the tree
for child in tree:
    if "type" in child.attrib:
        if child.attrib["type"] == "block_uid_v2_t":
            print(child.tag, child.attrib)

# List comprehension to store all relevant nodes in a list
regs = [child.attrib for child in tree if ("type" in child.attrib and child.attrib["type"]=="block_uid_v2_t")]

# Store only 'regname' of relevant nodes
reg_ids = [child.attrib["regname"] for child in tree if ("type" in child.attrib and child.attrib["type"]=="block_uid_v2_t")]
```

Comment: I need only the value "block_uid_v2_t" of type. How can i get?

Comment: @sudheerdivi You need to specify a little better: I've edited the answer to print *all* attributes of a node/child when it has the attribute `type` *and* this is equal to `block_uid_v2_t`. **Now, what do you want to do?** Do you want to *count* the number of nodes with this specific `type`, or do you want to get the `regname`s of all nodes of this type ... or something else?

Comment: Example: <reg regname="uid_v2" type="block_uid_v2_t" num="1" addr="0x4" incr="0x4">  In this tag i need only "block_uid_v2_t" only. that value i need to print in output file. simlarly,the addr and all.

Comment: @sudheerdivi I'm sorry, I still don't understand what you want. The code I've provided is easily adjustable. Have you tried changing it to accheive what you need?